# Migrating routes from old format to new one, where is the docs for this? Missing?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing, symfony-2.7

As perhaps you may notice from my previous recently post I'm working on SF2.0.x app to new SF2.7. Right now I'm having a lot of `NOTICE` and they don't affect app functionality but it will do and I want to prevent this. I have read [Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) chapter at SF Book, [The Routing Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html) and also [@ Route and @Method](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html) annotations but can't find any helpful to fix the issue. So I need some help from people here. Right now, the routes, looks like the one below (in XML format):

```
<route id="PDOneBundle_repproject_process" path="/project/{page}/{action}">
    <default key="_controller">PDOneBundle:ProjectDetail:process</default>
    <requirement key="page">\w+</requirement>
    <requirement key="action">add|update|delete</requirement>
    <requirement key="_format">html</requirement>
    <requirement key="_method">POST|GET</requirement>
</route>
```

And the message below is the `NOTICE` I am getting:

> DEPRECATED - The "_method" requirement is deprecated since version 2.2
>   and will be removed in 3.0. Use the setMethods() method instead or the
>   "methods" option in the route definition.

What is the right way to define the routes now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read this:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md

And the part you searched:

```
Routing

    Some route settings have been renamed:
    The pattern setting for a route has been deprecated in favor of path
    The _scheme and _method requirements have been moved to the schemes and methods settings

Before:

article_edit:
   pattern: /article/{id}
   requirements: { '_method': 'POST|PUT', '_scheme': 'https', 'id': '\d+' }

<route id="article_edit" pattern="/article/{id}">
   <requirement key="_method">POST|PUT</requirement>
   <requirement key="_scheme">https</requirement>
   <requirement key="id">\d+</requirement>
</route>

$route = new Route();
$route->setPattern('/article/{id}');
$route->setRequirement('_method', 'POST|PUT');
$route->setRequirement('_scheme', 'https');

After:

article_edit:
   path: /article/{id}
   methods: [POST, PUT]
   schemes: https
   requirements: { 'id': '\d+' }

<route id="article_edit" path="/article/{id}" methods="POST PUT" schemes="https">
   <requirement key="id">\d+</requirement>
</route>

$route = new Route();
$route->setPath('/article/{id}');
$route->setMethods(array('POST', 'PUT'));
$route->setSchemes('https');
```

Comment: I'm seeing this other message `DEPRECATED - The Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::getFactoryService method is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0.` I read the UPGRADE link you leave but there is nothing helpful there, what should I do in order to get this out too?

Comment: In fact if no infos are found, you will have to open `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition`, look the `getFactoryService`function and read the comment who will normally say what to use as a replacement.
Some bundles still use some deprecated functions, unless it is your own code, you can't do anything but deactivate the deprecated warning.